# mincha at tzet hacochavim

Tags: halacha, mincha-afternoon-prayer, sunset-shekia, orach-chaim

As far as I’m aware, the latest time for mincha is shkia (sunset). But I was at a new synagogue this shabbat and i asked what time mincha was. The rabbi told me “tzet hacochavim”. I couldn’t tell if he was joking or being serious. Are there any halachic sources for this? Is it just a minhag?

Thanks

Comment: Many (if not most) rishonim held mincha could be prayed until tzet hacochavim, but I'm not aware of any opinion who holds it is prayes at [or after] tzet hacochavim. Did you misunderstand?

Comment: Maybe they follow Rabbeinu Tam and he meant what's commonly known as tzet?